# pgRouting "Can't find Table"

Tags: postgis, postgresql, pgrouting, topology, pgadmin-3

I am using pgRouting version 2.1.0.
I am using pgAdmin III.

I have created a street network using Anita Graser's guide: https://anitagraser.com/2013/07/06/pgrouting-2-0-for-windows-quick-guide/

But now I have to create a topology using pgr_createTopology and it seems to error out saying the table name can not be found.

The error message:

```
NOTICE:  pgr_createTopology('street_network',1e-08,'geom','gid','source','target','true')
NOTICE:  Performing checks, please wait .....

NOTICE:  ----> PGR ERROR in pgr_createTopology: Table street_network not found

HINT:    ----> Check your table name

CONTEXT:  SQL statement "SELECT _pgr_onError(err, reportErrs, fnName, 'Table ' || tab ||' not found',' Check your table name', 'Table '|| tab || ' found')"
PL/pgSQL function _pgr_gettablename(text,integer,text) line 64 at PERFORM
SQL statement "select * from _pgr_getTableName('street_network',2,'pgr_createTopology' )"
PL/pgSQL function pgr_createtopology(text,double precision,text,text,text,text,text,boolean) line 48 at EXECUTE statement

NOTICE:  Unexpected error raise_exception
```

The table name does exist though, is there any fix to this?

Code I am using:

```
select pgr_createTopology('street_network', 0.00000001, 'geom', 'gid');
```

I have also tried to force my search path using:

```
set search_path = scratch, public;
```

Comment: Have you tried doing SELECT * FROM street_network; to confirm it works? Perhaps you have a casing problem like table is really Street_Network

Comment: try to add schema name in front of your table...

Comment: I apologize for the delay. The issue is that you need the appropriate privileges. A superuser or owner had to run createTopology for me.